# Logout link with thymeleaf and spring

Tags: java, spring

I got the following form, that's the part where my form is at. Just some scriptsand a regular navigation menu. there's no javascript code that could prevent the form from sending. Also removed all scripts and angular.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">


 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Spring Landing Page</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <form th:action="@{/logout-custom}" method="GET" 
 name="logoutForm" id="logout">
      <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
 </form>
```

And logging out with this controller (Also tried without this):

```
    //Logout
@RequestMapping(value="/logout-custom", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RedirectView logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    return new RedirectView("/loginForm.html");
}

/*Invalidates HTTP Session ,then unbinds any objects bound to it.
  Removes the Authentication from the SecurityContext to prevent issues with 
  concurrent requests.
  Explicitly clears the context value from the current thread.*/
```

Security part is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
 // Authentication : User --> Roles
 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
         throws Exception {
     auth.    
             inMemoryAuthentication()   //Test user data
             .withUser("user")
             .password("1234")
             .roles("USER");
 } 


 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
         .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/cont/**").access("hasRole('USER')")  // Allows 
              just logged in users to visit cont/...
             .and()

             .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login")
             .defaultSuccessUrl("/login-success", true)   // specifies login 
              page after successful login
             .failureUrl("/failLogin.html")
             .permitAll()

             .and()

 .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()

       .and()
       .csrf()
       .disable();
 }
```

The login is this way

```
    @GetMapping("/login-success")
    public RedirectView loginSuccess(RedirectAttributes attributes) {
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("flashAttribute", 
    "redirectWithRedirectView");
    attributes.addAttribute("attribute", "redirectWithRedirectView");
    return new RedirectView("/cont/home.html");
    }
    // redirects after validating user input and clicking on submit.
```

When i click the logout button, nothing happens. Even if it's the same as my login. The logout on't be triggered.
Maybe you got some ideas why.

Appreciate all help!

Comment: Is the `logoutPage` method part of the same controller as your login method ?

Comment: Yea, they're in the same controller.

Comment: Why are you working around Spring Security to do the logout? It already does all that and more for you. How to use it is documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token-form)

Comment: @M.Deinum So u ay i should just use the form and the security .logout().logOutUrl()? And no extra controller?

Comment: exactly, as Spring Security does all of that for you and more (doing callbacks, logging, firing events etc.).

Comment: I just tried so, but it stil didn't solve the problem that my form isn't submitted.

Comment: When using the default endpoint you should POST to the endpoint not GET.

Comment: @M.Deinum Now it says "Method POST not supported"

Comment: Then you are posting to the wrong URL.

Comment: I am just posting to another html file in the same directory.. What shall I do instead? At the login I am doing the same and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add a method in your controller to map the logout. Spring Security already handles this for you, unless you want to customized it. If so, you need to use another url, other than the one used in the Spring Security configuration. If not, Spring Security will have more priority over that URL. So instead of `/logout`, try something like `/logout-custom` for instance.